# Is it possible to prove existence of the circle.

Tags: circles

Is it possible to demonstrate a geometric proof to prove the existence of a circle? In Euclid's first proposition, he uses circles to prove the existence of an equilateral triangle, yet does not start by proving the existence of the circle.

Is this because Euclid thought the circle's existence was self-evident, or is there some way to prove the circle exists?

Thanks.